# kubernetes dashboard not able to launch

Tags: git, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Installed the kubernetes master node on Ubuntu 16.04.03 ( GCP instance ). all went good but not able to  launch the dashboard. i did open firewall port 8001 for
instance subnet. New/first time install so i might be missing something please advise. After running kubectl proxy , i am trying to access dashboard through external ip of instance like: http://35.196.xx.xx:8001/ui

```
la@kube-master:~$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                  READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
etcd-kube-master                      1/1       Running   0          17m
kube-apiserver-kube-master            1/1       Running   0          17m
kube-controller-manager-kube-master   1/1       Running   0          17m
kube-dns-545bc4bfd4-knw2b             3/3       Running   0          26m
kube-flannel-ds-bpm8c                 1/1       Running   0          17m
kube-proxy-k649v                      1/1       Running   0          26m
kube-scheduler-kube-master            1/1       Running   0          17m

la@kube-master:~$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://10.142.0.2:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://10.142.0.2:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns
/proxy

la@kube-master:~$ kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   29m
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an [add-on that you need to install](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard). Some installation methods automatically add it, but it seems like your method of choice didn't.

To deploy Dashboard execute following command:

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

To start using Dashboard run following command:

```
$ kubectl proxy
```

Dashboard is now available at http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/.

If you're running on Google Cloud, why not use [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/)? It's much easier to deploy and manage. It even comes with a [built-in dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes).

Comment: yaa GCE there but want to try out on standard machine.  i deployed the dashboard cmd: kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml. and run the proxy with diff port but still preview on cloud CLI still not working.
la@kube-master:~$ kubectl proxy --port=8080
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: I believe somehow i have to map my instance external ip here because localhost ip ( https://localhost:8080 ) is not equivalent to instance ip address.

Comment: If you just want to get to know Kubernetes, I recommend getting started with [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/).